# Parse cmd input with fewer lines of code

Tags: c++, input, getline

Can I do this with fewer lines of code?

```
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);        
    istringstream ss(input);
    vector<int> v;
    int n;
    while (ss >> n)
    {
        v.push_back(n);
    }
```

EDIT: I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: is this c++11 or c++14 specific ?

Comment: Why do you **need** fewer lines of code?

Comment: Well, I added the tags because I thought maybe there is something new to do this. I need fewer lines of code because I do really simple things and need to write a lot of code and use a lot of variables...

Comment: Need more content and description of what you are doing in order to recommend optimizations.  Such as an example of your input file.

Comment: `getline` isn't from C by the way?

Comment: I edited the question maybe it is better now.

Comment: Maybe the while loop can be done with `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(v));`

Comment: You can knock a few statements together by using a std::istream_iterator on a temp istringstream perhaps in a for loop? Bah! Beaten by @Olaf!

Comment: You are taking a leap of faith here that the user is entering `int` types only (separated by spaces).  No error checking is being done. Maybe you actually want _more_ lines of code?

Comment: @OlafDietsche - that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @MartinBonner I haven't tested this, so it may work, maybe not.

Comment: I tested it. It works. Thank you very much. I would definitely accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Why is the second parameter `std::istream_iterator<int>()`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop - reading from an input stream, and putting the values in a container - may be replaced with [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(v));
```

where `std::istream_iterator<int>(ss)` denotes the start of the input, `std::istream_iterator<int>()` is end of input, and finally `std::back_inserter(v)` is where the values go (doing a v.push_back()).

Although, keep in mind that this breaks on non-numerical input.

---

See also [std::copy - Parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

> **Parameters**
>   **first, last** -   the range of elements to copy
>   **d_first** -   the beginning of the destination range.

and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) or rather [`std::back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator)